# Accessing public static members of a base class specified as private

Tags: c++, oop, static-members, derived-class

I'm learning C++. The documentation [learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/member-access-control-cpp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/member-access-control-cpp) says:

> When you specify a base class as private, it affects only nonstatic members. Public static members are still accessible in the derived classes.

However, the following code slightly adjusted from the example following the previous quote cause error C2247:

> 'Base::y' not accessible because 'Derived1' uses 'private' to inherit from 'Base'.

I will appreciate any help with this situation.

```
class Base
{
public:
    int x;             
    static int y;      
};

class Derived1 : private Base
{
};

class Derived2 : public Derived1
{
public:
    int ShowCount();    
};

int Derived2::ShowCount()
{
    int cCount = Base::y;       
    return cCount;
}
```

Comment: Use `::Base::y` to get the scope right.

Comment: I think Microsoft's example is broken.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That documentation is a little misleading.

The correct compiler behaviour is for `Base::y` *and* `Base::x` to *both* be inaccessible in `Derived`, if you use that notation to attempt to reach the `static` member.

But you *can* reach it via the *global namespace* (thereby circumventing `Derived1`) by using another scope resolution operator:

```
int Derived2::ShowCount()
{
    int cCount = ::Base::y;       
    return cCount;
}
```

Finally, don't forget to *define* `y` somewhere if you want the link stage to be successful.

Comment: The path-finding of the name lookup rules is very frustrating at times.

Comment: @Bathsheba Could you also please add explanation regarding why adding another scope resolution works in above example. It would be very helpful for me. Thanks!

Comment: @PravarJawalekar: I've added that. Informally, if you go via the *global namespace*, then you reach `Base` directly rather than going via `Derived1`.

Comment: I've always told people that visibility and accessibility are completely orthogonal. Guess, I'll have to eat crow thanks to another obscure corner case…

Comment: Dear @Bathsheba: Thank you very much for your kind and detailed reply. Sorry to bother you again. If `::Base` circumvent `Derived1`, why `::Base::x` does not work? Suppose that we have an `Derived2` object `d2`, is the `Base` which we access via `::Base` the base class subobject in `d2`?

Comment: @KarlEL You need an *instance* of `Base` to access `x`, as the latter is a non-`static` member.

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
Base::y;
```

to this;

```
::Base::y;
```